# Comparing Subqueries

Tags: postgresql

I have two subqueries. Here is the output of subquery A....

```
  id   |    date_lat_lng    | stat_total | rnum 
-------+--------------------+------------+------
 16820 | 2016_10_05_10_3802 |          9 |    2
 15701 | 2016_10_05_10_3802 |          9 |    3
 16821 | 2016_10_05_11_3802 |         16 |    2
 17861 | 2016_10_05_11_3802 |         16 |    3
 16840 | 2016_10_05_12_3683 |         42 |    2
 17831 | 2016_10_05_12_3767 |          0 |    2
 17862 | 2016_10_05_12_3802 |         11 |    2
 17888 | 2016_10_05_13_3683 |         35 |    2
 17833 | 2016_10_05_13_3767 |         24 |    2
 16823 | 2016_10_05_13_3802 |         24 |    2
```

and subquery B, in which date_lat_lng and stat_total has commonality with subquery A, but id does not.

```
  id   |    date_lat_lng    | stat_total | rnum 
-------+--------------------+------------+------
 17860 | 2016_10_05_10_3802 |          9 |    1
 15702 | 2016_10_05_11_3802 |         16 |    1
 17887 | 2016_10_05_12_3683 |         42 |    1
 15630 | 2016_10_05_12_3767 |         20 |    1
 16822 | 2016_10_05_12_3802 |         20 |    1
 16841 | 2016_10_05_13_3683 |         35 |    1
 15632 | 2016_10_05_13_3767 |         23 |    1
 17863 | 2016_10_05_13_3802 |          3 |    1
 16842 | 2016_10_05_14_3683 |         32 |    1
 15633 | 2016_10_05_14_3767 |         12 |    1
```

Both subquery A and B pull data from the same table. I want to delete the rows in that table that share the same ID as subquery A but only where `date_lat_lng` and `stat_total` have a shared match in subquery B.

Effectively I need:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE
id IN
(SELECT id FROM (subqueryA) WHERE
subqueryA.date_lat_lng=subqueryB.date_lat_lng
AND subqueryA.stat_total=subqueryB.stat_total)
```

Except I'm not sure where to place subquery B, or if I need an entirely different structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this,

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE
id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM subqueryA
JOIN subqueryB
  USING (id,date_lat_lng,stat_total)
)
```

Comment: This was close! Thanks. Just needed to remove `id` from the USING group.  `DELETE FROM table WHERE
id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM subqueryA
JOIN subqueryB
  USING (date_lat_lng,stat_total)
)`